# How do I write .level+1 as a selector in JQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A quick question. I have a series of DIVs with the following classes `.level1` `.level2` `.level3`

This is what I want to happen...When I hover over `.level1` I would like the selector to select `.level2`. In other words `.level`+1 whatever I hover over.

How do I write this in JavaScript or JQuery ...The **X** in the code is where I need this to go

```
$(".no-submenu").hover(function() {
  $.data(this, "timer", setTimeout($.proxy(function() {

    $( X ).hide();

  }, this), 700));
}, function() {
  clearTimeout($.data(this, "timer"));
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're in order you can use **[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** with a **[starts with attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**

```
$(this).next('[class^=level]').hide();
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/KH3Qj/)**

You can do a replacement with a function:

**edit:** added in the `+` to support multi digit levels

```
function replacer(num)  {
    return (parseInt(num, 10) + 1);
}
var selector = $(this).attr("class").replace(/([\d]+)$/,replacer);    
$("." + selector).hide();
```

So, in the case above `X = "." + selector`

### **[simplified jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8SPUa/)**

**[.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**
**[.parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)**

The above will work based purely on class names.... so the order of the DIVs is not important. If you know the order of the divs, you could use the jQuery **[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** selector.

Comment: @Nasir - what didn't work? what's your html look like? Did you look at the example? Also, you can probably use next()... I'll add it in.

Comment: @Nasir - Also, I just edited in the `+` in the regex... I forgot that initially... it makes the expression work with multiple digit levels.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but just what I thought of

```
var x = 1; // You are probably going to change this
$('.level'+x).hover(function() {
$('.level'+(x+1)).dosomething();
},function () {
$('.level'+(x+1)).dosomethingelse();
});
```